# Sql trigger not functioning

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STUDENT
BEFORE INSERT
ON STUDENT

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.ENO =NULL THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-21900, 'ENROLL_NO IS MISSING');
END IF;
END;
```

So this was my trigger definition
But when I try to NUll values its accepted

I'm learning

Comment: If you don't want to allow nulls in `ENO` why didn't you define it as NOT NULL?

Comment: @forpas I'm learning and Its an assignment Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `= null`, but `is null`:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bi_student
  2    BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENT
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    IF :NEW.ENO is NULL THEN
  6       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-21900, 'ENROLL_NO IS MISSING');
  7    END IF;
  8  END;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into student (eno, name) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into student (eno, name) values (null, 'Foot');
insert into student (eno, name) values (null, 'Foot')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of -21900 is out of
range
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BI_STUDENT", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BI_STUDENT'


SQL>
```

---

Though, why trigger? That's a `not null` constraint (most probably a primary key):

```
SQL> drop table student;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table student (eno number constraint pk_student primary key,
  2                        name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into student (eno, name) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into student (eno, name) values (null, 'Foot');
insert into student (eno, name) values (null, 'Foot')
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."STUDENT"."ENO")


SQL>
```

---

As of your second trigger (posted in a comment): if you show errors, then:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOTALMARKS
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENT
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5  :NEW.TOTAL: =:NEW.S1+:NEW.S2+:NEW.S3;
  6  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL="| | :NEW. TOTAL) ;
  7  END;
  8  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER TOTALMARKS:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/11     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ( @ % ; indicator

SQL>
```

This is the 2nd line in *excecutable* part of the trigger:

```
:NEW.TOTAL: =:NEW.S1+:NEW.S2+:NEW.S3;
1234567890123456
          ^
          |
       11th character
```

It says that you should've used `:=` and not `: =` (i.e. no space in between), but then you get another error:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOTALMARKS
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENT
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5  :NEW.TOTAL :=:NEW.S1+:NEW.S2+:NEW.S3;
  6  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL="| | :NEW. TOTAL) ;
  7  END;
  8  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER TOTALMARKS:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/22     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TOTAL="| | :NEW. TOTAL) ;
         END;" when expecting one of the following: (...)
```

You can't enclose strings into double quotes - use single ones. But, there's another error (consecutive pipe sign for concatenation), and yet another (no space between `:new` and `.total`), until finally it compiles:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOTALMARKS
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON STUDENT
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5  :NEW.TOTAL :=:NEW.S1+:NEW.S2+:NEW.S3;
  6  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL='|| :NEW.TOTAL) ;
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm learning and Its an assignment Question

Comment: OK; then `is null` is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: if you could help me one more time

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOTALMARKS 
BEFORE INSERT
ON STUDENT 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
:NEW.TOTAL: =:NEW.S1+:NEW.S2+:NEW.S3; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL="| | :NEW. TOTAL) ; 
END;                                                                                                                                                                                  This is the query and error :ERROR at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ":" when expecting one of the following:  := . ( @ % ; indicator

Comment: The website wont let me ask conseutive questions within 90 minutes

Comment: Have a look at edited answer.